# Django DecimalField Omitting Trailing Zeroes

Tags: django, forms, decimal

My form contains a `DecimalField` with the attributes `max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], blank=True, null=True`.

In my view, I receive the model returned by the form:

```
my_model = form.save(False)

# Do stuff with returned model
...

my_model.save()
```

When I come to access the value of the `DecimalField`, `price`, I get it without the trailing zeroes. Say the value entered in the form field was 50:

```
print(my_model.price)
# Prints 50
```

But when I get the model from scratch, then retrieve the price, I get it with the trailing zeroes.

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.get(id=my_model.id)
print(my_model.price)
# Prints 50.00
```

I am just wondering why this is the case.

Comment: Because Django uses a `Decimal`, but you stored a `float`/`int` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one of the problems with floating points is that they typically fail to represent a lot of *decimal* values. For example `0.3` can not be represented exactly.

On the other hand has Python a type called `Decimal` that does not work with the IEEE-754 floating point specifications. But by formatting it as a stream of decimal digits. As a result it can represent *decimal* numbers correctly, and perform calculations correctly (but it will have a hard time storing numbers in a compact way).

Since databases typically use such representation as well, Django thus uses a `Decimal` to prevent the loss of data when reading or writing to the database. This `Decimal` contains the precision, and prints numbers like `50` with their precision (so `50.00`).

Django however aims to accept all kinds of numerical values, including `int`s, `float`s, etc. In that case the values are converted to a decimal representation when you write these to the database.

So in case you assign for example an `int` to an attribute of a model instance, then that attribute will have type `int` (well it is basically the way you assign an attribute to a Python object). If you then store it in the database, Django will serialize it as a decimal, and it is stored that way in the database. If you later fetch the model, you have a model in memory, with as attribute a `Decimal`, that stores the number with the specified precision.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the detailed reply. It just seemed weird as one view was displaying it as 50, and another as 50.00, but yes as you say, I've just confirmed that the first one is reading it from memory and the second afresh.